# How to include additional product attributes into custom PHP array

Tags: php, adminhtml, product-attribute

I am assembling a product array drop-down for an extension I am building. I was curious if it is possible to pull a few more attributes into the following code so that I can reference them elsewhere in my code at the same time.

Currently, I am pulling all product SKUs from Magento using the following:

```
$products = array();
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSort('sku', 'asc');
$i = 1;
$items = $productCollection->getData();
foreach($items as $item) {
$products[$i]['value'] = $item['sku'];
$products[$i]['label'] = $item['sku'];
$i++;
}
```

I would like to also include the product's entity_id, created_at & updated_at fields into this array.

ADDITIONAL NOTES: Currently I just reference the SKUs using the following code in my admin HTML:

```
$products = array();
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSort('sku', 'asc');
$i = 1;
$items = $productCollection->getData();
foreach($items as $item) {
$products[$i]['value'] = $item['sku'];
$products[$i]['label'] = $item['sku'];
$i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku','created_at','updated_at'))
    ->addAttributeToSort('sku', 'asc');

$products = array();
foreach($productCollection as $item) {
    $products[] = array(
        'entity_id' => $item->getId(),
        'value' => $item->getData('sku'),
        'label' => $item->getData('sku'),
        'created_at' => $item->getData('created_at'),
        'updated_at' => $item->getData('updated_at')
    );
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to echo out certain indexes of the array from here? For example, I wanted to echo the entity_id by doing 'echo $products[0]' or perhaps to see the created_at value I would do 'echo $products[3]'. I tried several variations but not seeing any results. The code itself works as described though which is great!

Comment: `<?php echo $products[0]['entity_id'] ?>`. Keep in mind that my logic will have the $products first array key index start at zero, whereas your original logic the original array key index would have been 1.

Answer (score 0):

Deeper you can convert an collection to array using function `toArray`
 **Code:**

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSort('sku', 'asc')
        ->addAttributeToselect('sku')->addAttributeToselect('entity_id');

$items=$productCollection->toArray();

foreach($items as $item):
    echo $item['sku'];        
    echo $item['entity_id'];
endforeach;
```

Comment: There is no need for `->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')`. All resource model collections will include the entity's primary key as part of the select query automatically.